# In which directory is the opennms logo on the home page located?

Tags: centos, opennms

I'm using a Centos machine and would like to change the opennms logo on the home page,
which logo file should I replace?, a location for the file to replace would be good.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The opennms logo is located in `${OPENNMS_HOME}/jetty-webapps/opennms/images/logo.png`

Simply replace that logo and you are good to go.

I am not sure where your ${OPENNMS_HOME} is. On my system it is `/opt/opennms`.